# Save Image in External Storage

Tags: android, android-studio

my problem is , When I click on picture , it shows the saved message But the photo will not be saved.I also allowed access to external storage WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
    if(isExternalStorageWriteable()) {
        FileOutputStream outputStream;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.img3);
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), "MyImage.png");
        try {
                outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputStream);
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Toast.makeText(this,"Pic Created :  "+file,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    } else {
            Toast.makeText(this,"SDCard Not is Ready",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show(); } }
public boolean isExternalStorageWriteable()
{
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    return Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state); }
```

[image]

Comment: Your `Toast` about picture created is in wrong place and it will show up even if an error occurs. Check your `logcat`, there is probably some exception printed. Update your question with the exception stacktrace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I also allowed access to external storage WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" in the manifest or you asked for the permission at runtime?

I guess you are having this problem only on devices with Android version >= 23 (6.0).
You should check if you have the permission to write in the external storage before doing it, and in case you should ask for permission:

```
ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity, Manifest.permission. WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
```

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

If permission is granted check for stacktrace and post it here, for sure the "Pic Created" toast should stay inside the try-catch at the end of the block, and inside the catch blocks you would have to launch a negative toast.